# Magento 2 Cart empty using Memcache

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, memcached

I am using Magento2.2.2 with memcache.

Facing some issue with memcache with-out memcache adding cart is working fine and cart page showing added items.

If enable memcache and configured `env.php` after click addtocart showing success message item added to cart but cart page is empty.

My `env.php` configurations

```
array (
'save' => 'memcached',
'save_path' => 'localhost:11211',
),
```

Any Answer will appreciate.

Comment: Please check in Magento admin configuration cookies domain configuration is right way some time issue because cookie domain not configure right way.